# Google calendar add event with redirect url

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add a button to my website that will add an event to my google calendar, I found this url:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=Your+Event+Name&dates=20140127T224000Z/20140320T221500Z&details=For+details,+link+here:+http://www.example.com&location=Waldorf+Astoria,+301+Park+Ave+,+New+York,+NY+10022&sf=true&output=xml

which works and it's really handy to configure, but I'm wondering, because when I click on it, it takes me to google calendar and it will never come back to my site.

Is there a possibility to add a some parameter to once the event is added, make google calendar redirect to my website?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not a way to do this. Your best bet is to have this link open in a new tab/window so that the user still has your site open.

Another option is to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/) if you're adding a lot of events for a user and have them authenticate. This way you can just use an API to add events and keep them on the page. I would not suggest this solution if you're just adding an event here and there as it's quite invasive to give calendar access to an application.